# Prompt for string and read and then display in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I've spent a few days playing around with OCaml

```
let prompt_user() = print_string "Enter a string\n";;
let read_user_input2() =
  prompt_user();
  input_line stdin;;
```

When run, nothing happens, but I can start entering information. Only after entering the string does the actual prompt appear:

```
# read_user_input();;
hello
Enter a string
You entered hello
- : string = "hello"
#
```

Can someone tell me how I should be reordering my program so that the prompt appears before the input stage?

Many TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output channel is buffered, but `print_string` does not flush the buffer. `print_endline` and `print_newline` does, however, as does `flush` of course, so either of these should work:

```
let prompt_user () = print_endline "Enter a string"
```

```
let prompt_user () =
  print_string "Enter a string";
  print_newline ()
```

```
let prompt_user () =
  print_string "Enter a string\n";
  flush stdout
```